# SQL Server : alter table type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What happens when you execute the same `alter column` several times, e.g:

```
ALTER table1 ALTER column column1 varchar(40)
ALTER table1 ALTER column column1 varchar(40)
...
```

Does SQL Server compare altering types in first place or does it use the same mechanism for every `alter`?

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: The first command changes the column's datatype to `varchar(40)` - and so does the second command .....

Comment: I analyze someone's intall scripts, and there are thhe same alters without checking column types. So there is not any diffrence in each alter exec ? sql-server will not check type before trying to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the transaction log, or use table change tracking, or use CDC to track, then you will find out what id the difference between first time and second time. You will see no difference.